# Server error in Android Volley only on 'if (isChecked)' in onCheckedChanged

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I'm using volley to connect to an amazon database and change a specific value in a table between "ON" and "OFF". I'm using onCheckedChanged and StringRequest to do this, and it successfully changes the value to "OFF" if it is manually set to "ON". When I try to change from "OFF" to "ON", however, I get a server error from volley ("com.android.volley.ServerError") and the value remains unchanged. My php is being hosted locally at the moment, and my login and register methods also work fine.

Java:

```
ToggleButton light = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.lightSwitch);
light.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOG_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(DiningRoom.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(DiningRoom.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            MySingleton.getInstance(DiningRoom.this).addToRequestqueue(stringRequest);
        }else{
            StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOG_URL2,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(DiningRoom.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(DiningRoom.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            MySingleton.getInstance(DiningRoom.this).addToRequestqueue(stringRequest2);
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:
When this script is loaded from browser, it successfully changes the value from off to on. The error only occurs when it's run through android volley.

```
<?php
include 'dbConnect.php';

mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Component SET component_status = 'ON' WHERE component_id = 10");

?>
```

I have a second php file to handle switching from on to off.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your component_status is boolean or tinyint(1). Becuase while creating the table I gave the type as boolean when I describe the table I got the type as tinyint(1).

user `desc 'tableName'` to see the table description.

if the type is tinyint change your query to

```
"UPDATE Component SET component_status = 1 WHERE component_id = 10"
```

Refer 1 as ON and 0 as OFF.

Hope this will help for you.